# absolute positioning within relative div firefox

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I'm having trouble with absolute positioning an image in a relative positioned div. The image should be centered within the div. For this I use following css

```
div
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
div img 
{
  margin-top: -10px; /*img width is 20px*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

This works great on all browsers except Firefox. 
Is there any workaround for this? Because i searched already a lot for this and i can't figure something out.

PS: Don't say to me to use line-height. Because there is also text next to the image. So this option will not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the image you say `top: 50%`. 50% of what? It should be 50% of the parent element. What is the parent element set to? If it's not set to anything, therein lies the problem.

Comment: What are you talking about? 50% of the parent which is the div!

Comment: @McTrafik - Yes but that div is not set to anything. So there is no reference for 50% and hence the question, 50% of what?

Answer (score 1):

why not do something like this

```
div
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div img
{
  position: relative;
  top:25%;
  left:50%;
}
```

The `relative` for the image means `25%` from the top of the `div` and `50%` for the left side.

Comment: I tried this, but `top: 25%` doesn't do anything. left is working but i need top positioning specifically

Comment: Try giving the `div` a specific height. I.E. The size of the image + padding/margin should work

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it as a background image if you just want the image there.

```
div
    {
      background-image: url('image.jpg');
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin: 0px auto;
      position: relative;
      width: Xpx;
      height: Xpx;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

and for the text use a div inside and position it using margin, padding or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

How about auto margins:

```
div img 
{
  margin-top: -10px; /*img with is 20px*/
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This works for me in firefox 7

Comment: You'll need display: block and position: absolute for this to work, but auto margins are good for centred things.

Comment: horizontal margin will work. But i need to vertically align the image

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but to vertically align the image you can use 'margin-top: 25%;' in addition to the above. But you'll have to set the number manually - auto doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: red;
    width:500px;
}
div img {
    margin-top: -10px; 
    //position: absolute; /*get it out*/
    display: block; /*Important*/
    margin: auto; /*Important*/
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article on the subject from CSS-Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/